# Tuning kafka performance to get 1 Million messages/second

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm using 3 VM servers, each one has 16 core/ 56 GB Ram /1 TB, to setup a kafka cluster. I work with Kafka 0.10.0 version. I installed a broker on two of them. I have created a topic with 2 partitions, 1 partition/broker and without replication.

My goal is to attend 1 000 000 messages / second.

I made a test with kafka-producer-perf-test.sh script and i get between 150 000 msg/s and 204 000 msg/s.

My configuration is:

-batch size: 8k (8192)

-message size: 300 byte (0.3 KB)

-thread num: 1

The producer configuration:

-request.required.acks=1

-queue.buffering.max.ms=0 #linger.ms=0

-compression.codec=none

-queue.buffering.max.messages=100000

-send.buffer.bytes=100000000

Any help will be appreciated to get 1 000 000 msg / s

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You're running an old version of Apache Kafka. The most recent release (0.11) had improvements including around performance.

You might find this useful too: https://www.confluent.io/blog/optimizing-apache-kafka-deployment/